# Absolute continuity of increasing functions on an interval

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, absolute-continuity

I have been using Real Analysis by Royden and Fitzpatrick. I am currently stuck on problem 39 of chapter 6. The problem is stated as follows:

"Use the preceding problem to show that if f is increasing on [a, b], then f is absolutely continuous on [a, b] if and only if for each $\epsilon$ , there is a $\delta$ > 0 such that for a measurable subset
E of [a, b],
m*(f(E))< $\epsilon$ if m(E) <$\delta$"

(m* denotes outer measure and m denotes lebesgue measure)

I can see why absolute continuity implies the other property. However, I fail to see how absolute continuity follows from the fact that f is increasing and that for each $\epsilon$ , there is a $\delta$ > 0 such that for a measurable subset
E of [a, b],
m*(f(E))< $\epsilon$ if m(E) <$\delta$"

My approach is to take $\delta$ responding to $\epsilon$. Then for any finite collection of disjoint open interval ($a_k$,$b_k$) such that $\sum_{k=1}^n (b_k-a_k) < \delta$ we have that m*$(f(\cup_{k=1}^n(a_k, b_k)))<\epsilon$. I cannot see how this implies $\sum_{k=1}^n |f(b_k)-f(a_k)|<\epsilon$ as required for absolute continuity.

Is this a good approach to solve this problem? Any advice would be appreciated!

EDIT:

The previous problem (Q38):

Show that f is absolutely continuous on [a, b] if and only if for each $\epsilon$ > 0, there is a $\delta$ > 0 such that for every countable disjoint collection ${(a_k, b_k)}$ of open intervals in (a, b), if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |b_k-a_k|<\delta$ then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |f(b_k)-f(a_k)|<\epsilon$

Comment: The fact that $f$ is increasing means that f maps intervals to intervals

Comment: What about discontinuities f may have? Since f is increasing it would only have jump discontinuities. Although the endpoints $a_k$ and $b_k$ may be close to one another, how can we ensure that |$f(a_k)-f(b_k)$| can be made small if |$b_k-a_k$| is small enough? I can see how the proof would work in the case f were continuous.

Comment: Sorry- I had in mind a continuous function. Perhaps it is possible to use the fact that measurable increasing functions have at most countably many discontinuities (jump discontinuities in this case).

Comment: F: [0,1] -> R where F(x) = x for x in [0, 1/2] and F(x)=x+1 for x in (1/2, 1]. I cannot see why this function would not be a counter example. F is increasing and for a small measurable set E, I think m*(F(E)) is also small but the function is not continuous on [0,1]. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you also show the preceding problem?

Comment: @AlexVong, I have added the previous question to the original post

Comment: Is $m^*$ the same as $m$?

Comment: m* denotes outer measure while m is lebesgue measure

Comment: maybe the question should have been, for all measurable $E$, $m^*(E) < \epsilon$ if $m( f^{-1}(E)) < \delta$? (ps Q38 but not Q39 is in the errata http://www2.math.umd.edu/~pmf/docs/Real%20Analysis.pdf )

Comment: This change to the question would make a lot of sense. Thank you! I think the result also holds if f is continuous

Comment: I don't agree with my suggested modification anymore, because i think it makes the cantor function AC when it shouldn't be...perhaps the correct fix is to set f continuous at the beginning.